# ffmpeg transcode and avfilter error

Tags: c, ffmpeg, transcoding

FFmpeg configure options:

```
--enable-avfilter \
--enable-nonfree \
--disable-filters \
--enable-filter=movie \
--enable-filter=overlay \
--enable-filter=null \
--enable-filter=anull \
--enable-filter=scale \
--enable-filter=rotate \
```

and run success use

```
filter_spec = "null"; /* passthrough (dummy) filter for video */
```

and get the transcoding video success!
but use

```
filter_spec = "movie=/storage/emulated/0/image.png [wm]; [in][wm] overlay=10:10 [out]";
```

then run to

```
if ((ret = avfilter_graph_parse_ptr(filter_graph, filter_spec,
    &inputs, &outputs, NULL)) < 0)
        goto end;
```

get the error:

Invalid data found when processing input

please help me...